# Idiomatic way to select one element of array, with probability depending on a field of the element

Tags: javascript, algorithm, language-agnostic, underscore.js

Let's say I have this array:

```
[{name: "A", works: true}, {name: "B", works: true}, {name: "C", works: false}]
```

I want a function to select one element of this array, with, let's say `80%` probability of getting a working element (`works: true`).

How could I do this elegantly? Would appreciate pseudo-code or code in any language.

(I can use `underscore.js` if needed, if using js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation first you are willing to toss a coin to decide if you are going to pick a working element or less. This can be done in JS with `Math.random()` which returns a value in `[0,1]`.

```
value = Math.random() <= 0.8
```

will set value to true 80% of the times. At this point you already know which kind of element you want so you can just pick a random one and check if works or not. If it's of the correct type return it, otherwise pick another random one.

If your list is pretty long this may require many picks, in this case you could split the list and keep two lists (working ones and not workings ones).

Comment: Looks like a good approach. Here's an implementation (hopefully correct), in case anyone is interested - http://jsfiddle.net/XGGup/

Comment: I think there may be some problems in some cases. I think this approach is good for the first part of the solution, the second should be different. My proposal: 1) select which option ("works" or not) you will choose, by doing this check: `Math.random() <= probability_for_works`, 2) if the result is `true`, select random element from the list of elements that have `works` property set to `true`, otherwise select random element from the rest of elements. This way you will not have an option of randomly selecting elements you will then discard.

Comment: "_If your list is pretty long this may require many picks, in this case you could split the list and keep two lists (working ones and not working ones)_.". What you say is EXACTLY what I wrote to avoid re-picking elements if list contains many elements.

Answer (score 1):

The Function:

```
function chooser(an_array) {
    var node_found = false;
    var works = Math.random() <= .80;
    while(node_found === false) {
        var node = an_array[Math.floor(Math.random()*an_array.length)];
        if(node.works === works) node_found = true;
    }
    return node;
}
```

Edit: Decided I should test it. Runs through the above function 10,000 times, results are good: http://jsfiddle.net/YyZfA/4/

Comment: Why are you doing this [exactly as Jack](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13108897/548696)? There is a place for change, especially in the `while(node_found===false)` part (you can filter the elements before picking random one).

Comment: Generally if two people come up with a very similar solution it means one of two things. Either it's the correct one, or it was a very simple solution to arrive at, but not necessarily correct. This one is both simple and correct. I think you may be implying that I copied Jack in some way, though. We answered this question at about the same time, I think, because I hadn't seen his solution until Stack Overflow notified me of your comment. Also, this isn't a place to come have people do your work for you. The asker should definitely improve on my method if he goes with it. This is just a start.

Comment: That is a wise comment, but explains only why you submitted similar solution. Agreed, this is not ideal and could be improved by OP. Anyway, no reason to remove it - it has complete code, which is not seen in the other answer.